# how to fix - invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: assembly

```
section .rodata
MSG:    DB  "welcome",10,0
S1: DB  "%d",10,0 ; 10 = '\n' , 0 = '\0'

section .data

array   DB 5,1,7,3,4,9,12,8,10,2,6,11
len DB 12   

section .text
    global main
    extern printf

main:   
    mov ecx,12  
    mov eax,0 
    xor esi, esi
    again:
        mov al, byte[array+esi]
        push al
        pop ebx 
        add eax,ebx 
        inc esi
        jmp again
    push eax    
    call printf
    mov eax, 1  ;exit system call
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Didn't the error message come with a line number? Also, you do have an inconsistent use of labeling, sometimes with colon (`:`) as in `MSG: DB ...` and sometimes no colon, as in `array DB ...`.

Comment: There is no `push r8`. Read the manual. Even if there were, it wouldn't do what you wanted, which is probably `movzx ebx, al` or `movzx ebx, byte[array+esi]` to skip a step.

Answer (score 2):

The `push al` instruction does not exist.
Even if it did exist then pushing a byte followed by popping a dword would leave you with an unbalanced stack.
Luckily this program didn't compile because it also does an infinite loop. You will want to change `jmp again` into `loop again`.